# How do I use mod rewrite to deny access to specific URL generated by PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lamp

I am running a LAMP server on ubuntu and I want to restrict access to a login page URL to localhost for security reasons at the level of the `apache2.conf` file. (The login URL looks like `/wiki/foo.php?id=start&do=login`) **without** restricting access to the rest wiki.

To reiterate, we are restricting access to the login function only, and NOT restricting access to `foo.php?whateverelse&something`, etc. - e.g. we only want to restrict access specifically to the `?id=start&do=login` part of the URL. How do we do this with a LAMP server?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following using mod_rewrite in the server config to serve a 403 Forbidden if the client making the request for that specific URL does not have the IP address `127.0.0.1` (ie. localhost):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=start&do=login$
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/foo\.php$ - [F]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule